# DOM html get height do not exactly when use insertBefore jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, append

I use RoR to render file js

render file js:

```
<% @screen_shots.each do |s| %>
  $('<%= j render "item", :s => s %>').insertBefore('.form-upload');
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //"preview-screenshot-<%= s.id%>" is element insertBefore to ".form-upload"
    c = document.getElementById("preview-screenshot-<%= s.id%>");
    console.log(c.clientHeight);
  });

<% end %>
```

I want to get height of above elements but do not exactly.

Console write = 58px, when I check element with f12 so height = 412px.
(css don't unrelated here)

How to fix this?

render file item.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3" style="padding: 0 8px;">
  <div class="preview" style=" <%= style_for_screen_shot(s)%>" id='<%="screen-shot-#{s.id}"%>'>
    <div class="phone-image">
      <%= link_to screen_shot_path(s), method: :delete, remote: true, data: { type: :json }, class: "remove-screen-shot" do %>
        <span class="badge label-default" style="position: absolute;top: 10px;right: 10px;font-weight: bold;">X</span>
      <% end %>
      <p class="preview-caption"> <%= s.text %></p>
      <%= image_tag s.image_url, class: "preview-screenshot ", id: "preview-screenshot-#{s.id}"%>
      <%= image_tag "imgpsh.png", class: "preview-bg"%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="setting">
    <div class="setting-head">Layout & Style</div>
    <div class="setting-caption">
      <label for="setting-caption">Caption</label>
      <textarea class="form-control update-text" id="setting-caption" data-id= "<%= s.id%>" data-url="<%= screen_shot_set_screen_shot_path(@screen_shot_set, s) %>">  <%= s.text %> </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="setting-more">
      <div class="setting-more-btn dropup" >
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Change Color & Background <span class="caret"></span> </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 100%; padding: 15px;">
          <%= form_for s, class: "", :remote => true, :html => {:'data-type' => "json"} do |f|%>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td> <%= f.label :color%> </td> <td style="padding: 5px;"> <%= f.color_field :color%> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <%= f.label :bg_color%> </td> <td style="padding: 5px;"> <%= f.color_field :bg_color%> </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <%= f.submit "Changes", :class => "btn btn-success", style: "width: 100%;" %>
              </div>
            </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `preview-screenshot-<%= s.id%>` Is this your id ?

Comment: yes, id of element

Comment: normally this happens when you get the height before elements inside are fully loaded. Could this be the case for you? you have an image inside it ?

Comment: yes, inside have a image.

Comment: how to get height of div after append div complete (image load complete)